# Nifi secure parameter storage for passwords and other sensitive fields

Tags: mongodb, passwords, apache-nifi, password-protection

I would like to securely store a password via the [parameter context](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#parameter-contexts) feature in Apache Nifi.  From what is displayed in the UI, `parameters` seem more powerful and preferred over `variables`.  When I setup a `sensitive value` parameter, this works but then requires that any fields that leverage/use it also be sensitive.  So for example, I have a MongoDB password.  Since the [GetMongo](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mongodb-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.GetMongo/) processor `Mongo URI` field is not sensitive, I can only reference a non-sensitive parameter but it still just shows the password in plaintext in the UI.  Are there any other methods for securely storing secrets and referencing them in Nifi such that they're safe but also easily parameterized?  Should/could `GetMongo` be refactored to split out the username and password fields to properly mark the password as being sensitive, similar to how the `DBCPConnectionPool` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sensitive parameters is the correct approach. The GetMongo processor should be refactored to have a specific property for the password and it should be marked as sensitive so that it can leverage sensitive parameters. Feel free to file a JIRA for this improvement - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI.